# How do I resolve an infinite Javascript promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, apollo, react-apollo

I'm using the Apollo GraphQL library, and at one point it returns a promise.  I can see that it's a resolved promise when I inspect it in the console:

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved", [[PromiseValue]]: Object}
__proto__
:
Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]
:
"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]
:
Object
```

However, when I `Promise.resolve(thatPromise`) I get back ... the same promise.  No matter how many times I resolve the promise, it keeps returning a promise, making it impossible to access the promise's value.

I know the value is in there (if I inspect `[[PromiseValue]]` it's a plain object with values) ... I just can't figure out how to get it out at the code level instead of in the browser console.

Has anyone ever run in to something like this, and if so were you able to figure out how to extract the value of such an infinitely resolving promise?

P.S. I did try:

```
thatPromise['[[PromiseValue]]'];
```

but it appears to be a special browser value that you can't access from the code.

P.P.S. Just realized it may or may not actually be a promise.  I get it by calling `response.clone().json()`, so while it looks like a promise maybe it's just a clone of a promise, in which case that might explain why I can't resolve it.  However, it doesn't explain how I can extract the value.

***EDIT***

I think there's weirdness going on here and I'm not reporting all of the relevant details.  Will post more info as soon as I sort things out better (don't want to send anyone on a wild goose chase).

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you are trying. 'Promise.resolve(thatPromise)' is supposed to return what you pass in. It doesn't resolve the argument - it creates a promise that instantly resolves TO the argument.  So if you pass it a promise, you'll get a promise back.

Comment: I think because it was a clone of a promise (or something) Promise.resolve just returns the value itself ... which is somehow wrapping a value like a Promise, but not resolveable like a promise.

Comment: No Promise.resolve() doesn't return the original value, it returns a promise. Look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

Comment: Good luck! Hope you figure it out.

Comment: Er guess I can't delete; left an edit comment instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason for you to have to call `Promise.resolve` to get the value. Remember that Promises are asynchronous. You have to access it's value like this:

```
myPromise.then(value => {
  console.log(value)
  // do whatever you're going to do with value
};
```

You can read up more [here][1] on how Promises work.

Comment: Right, but if it's a resolved promise that I call `Promise.resolve` on then  `then` shouldn't be needed.  I think I somehow have a weird clone that looks like a promise but isn't or something.

Comment: Promise.resolve() will always return a Promise. Check the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve). You don't call Promise.resolve to read a promise, but to create a new one that's already resolved.

Comment: Yeah sorry; what I should have said is that even if I `Promise.resolve(response).then(x =>x)` then `x` is still a promise.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I was just being confused by the console.  There were some details involved, but your answer is essentially correct (if I do `.then` earlier before the clone I *can* access the value).  Thanks.